# File Synchronization in Eclipse through the Ubuntu One

Tags: java, eclipse, ubuntu, synchronization

I am working in two machines and using Ubuntu One to synchronize my files. When a create a workspace folder from Eclipse and a project (Java project for example) inside of my Ubuntu One path, it works fine the first time, but when a closed and open it in another machine, or sometimes the same machine, that project now get problems like doesn't show in the Package Explorer windows. The *.java and *.class files are synchronize well but looks like the project path o something similar get confuse.

I know that maybe is not the right way to synchronize my work, but in this moment is like that, perhaps I should change it to Git o something similar.

does somebody have any idea about the problem or a best way to do this synchronization?

Comment: There are a lot of files associated with a project in the workspace `.metadata` folder - are these being copied?

Comment: Looks like Ubuntu One synchronize too, .metadata in the project folder and workspace folder, I saw in both computers but I don't know if the content is the same.